# How do local rank trackers ping google maps rankings from specific gps points?

Tags: seo, google

There are a few services like Brightlocal or Whitespark that can show you rankings based on different parts of the city.

Can this be done manually? I would struggle to even find a proxy for a specific smaller city let alone ping rankings from a specific block. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Most (alL?) local rank trackers just use URL parameters instead of proxies.

**Relevant URL parameters**

The three relevant ones to localize search results are:

- `&hl=` for the language
- `&gl=` for the country
- `&uule=` for the exact geolocation with longitude and altitude

**Example**

Instead of using the URL `https://www.google.com/search?q=bakery` to look at the search results, they use `https://www.google.com/search?q=bakery&hl=en&gl=US&uule=a+cm9sZToxCnByb2R1Y2VyOjEyCnByb3ZlbmFuY2U6Ngp0aW1lc3RhbXA6MTY1ODU2MzQ3Mzg0MjAwMApsYXRsbmd7CmxhdGl0dWRlX2U3OjM3NDIxMDAwMApsb25naXR1ZGVfZTc6LTEyMjA4NDAwMDAKfQpyYWRpdXM6OTMwMDA%3D`

Ideally, also throw in `&pws=0` to avoid any kind of personalization.

**Free Tool**

Here is a free tool to translate an address into a geolocation and automatically start a Google search for it: https://valentin.app/